# ReactJS, functional components. So my state is given an initial value, then becomes undefined, and is then given a value during my useEffect

Tags: reactjs, state, undefined, react-functional-component

The part where my state becomes undefined prevents me from using the state later on in my return statement. I commented out where I want to use it so I can see the console logs, which is shown at the end of this post.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Card} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";


const StrainDetails = (props) => {
    // const [strains, setStrains] = useState([]);
    const [details, setDetails] = useState(['hi']);
    const [savedList, setSavedList] = useState([]);

    let strain = Object.keys(props.strains).slice(0, 20).map((y) => {return y});
    
    console.log(props)
    console.log(strain)

    useEffect(() => {
        setDetails(props.strains[props.match.params.strain]);
    }, [props.match.params.strain, props.strains])

    console.log(details);


    const addToSavedList = strain => {
        setSavedList([...savedList, strain]);
        console.log(savedList);
      };
    
    const saveStrain = () => {
        addToSavedList(strain);
    }

    return (
            <div className='container'>
                <Card>
                    <div className="strain-card">
                        <div className='name'>
                            {props.match.params.strain}
                        </div>
                        {/* <div className='id'>
                            ID: {details.id.toString()}
                        </div> */}
                        {/* <div className='type'>
                            Type: {details.race.toString()}
                        </div>
                        <div className='flavors'>
                            Flavors: {details.flavors.toString()}
                        </div>
                        <div className='effects'>
                            Medical effects: {details.effects.medical.toString()} <br />
                            Positive effects: {details.effects.positive.toString()} <br />
                            Negative effects: {details.effects.negative.toString()} <br />
                        </div> */}
                        <Button className='save' onClick={saveStrain}>Save</Button>
                    </div>
                </Card>
            </div>
        )
    }

    export default StrainDetails;
```

[Here is a pic of my console, check the log for StrainDetails.js:17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4yVE.png)

I want to make it so the state never becomes undefined. That way I can use the state without any errors, but I'm not sure what is causing it to become so.

[props.strains object data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgQLG.png)

`props.strains` is a very large data object, but right over it in the console where it says "hi", `setDetails` should already be triggered. (`["hi"]` is the `useState` for details).

Answer (score 1):

Check props.match.params.strain and props.strains are valid before setting it to the details.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(props.strains.length > 0 && props.match.params.strain) {
       setDetails(props.strains[props.match.params.strain]);
    }
}, [props.match.params.strain, props.strains])
```

You have to use a Router and withRouter(), to access props.match

import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";

```
export default withRouter(StrainDetails);
```

Comment: Hm, I understand what you did there. It doesn't return undefined, but now setDetails is not giving details a value. I checked the logs for props.strains and props.match.params.strain, and they both return something so I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: can you post your props.strains json data

Comment: alright I added it in the bottom of the original question post, I can't add images to comments

Comment: Sorry dude, It seems your code looks perfect. Only problem I think is in your props.match.params.strain. try to put console.log(props.match.params.strain) both inside and outside of useState and check does it has anything in it.

Comment: I have updated my anser, You have to use withRouter to access props.match in your component.

Comment: Yeah it's still doing the same thing. It's ok though, you had a great idea wrapping the setDetails in that if statement, so thanks a ton!